# Compiling boost::thread with Eclipse

Tags: c++, boost

I am using Ubuntu + Eclipse and installed boost(not sure correct). I installed Boost using apt-get install libboost*

I tested some simple code, it seems the boost working right.

However, when I try to learn the thread part, the code below does not work.

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp> 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void hello()
{
   cout<<"hello!"<<endl;
}   

int main()
{
    boost::thread thrd(&hello);
    cout<<"Just a test!"<<endl;
}
```

The error information is as follow, there are 4 errors.

```
Severity and Description Path Resource Location Creation Time Id
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp undefined reference to `boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'  FirstCppProject line 40 1260656497961 200


Severity and Description Path Resource Location Creation Time Id
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread()'  FirstCppProject line 191 1260656497967 202


Severity and Description Path Resource Location Creation Time Id
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp undefined reference to `vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'  FirstCppProject line 65 1260656497965 201


Severity and Description Path Resource Location Creation Time Id
undefined reference to `boost::thread::~thread()' FirstCppProject test.cpp line 15 1260656497959 199
```

Please forgive me if my question is too naive. Please offer any information you think might help me out.

Answer (score 4):

you have to link against the thread library libboost_thread_...

Comment: thanks for your quick comment. Is this a problem with Eclipse? So how to do that in Eclipse? I thought when I installed boost on Ubuntu, I don't have to anything with Eclipse.

Comment: No, it's not an eclipse problem, you'll have to specify an option for the linker (check the project options), something like -lboost_thread-gcc-4.3 or similar, you'll have to find the library first to figure out its name, you'll most likely have to link against pthread as well.

Comment: You will have to link against pthread. I've had to do this before.

Answer (score 1):

With Boost sometimes you just need to tell your linked where the libraries are and it will figure out which one to link against.

Comment: auto-linking doesn't work in g++, it's a visual c++ feature so it's not available under *nix

Answer (score 1):

To add a linker-> 
            1.right click on the project
            2.select on the properties window
           3.click on the c/c++ build
           4. choose setting 
             5. and choose libraries
          6. then u can add linkers: boost_thread and boost_system etc